# Isomorphism between rings $A/m^n \rightarrow \hat{A}/\hat{m}^n$.

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

In Lemma 7.25, pg. 115, of [Milnes' notes.](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf)

> For $n \ge 1$, the map $A/m^n \rightarrow \hat{A}/\hat{m}^n$ is an isomorphism.

$A$ is ring associated to a discrete valuation $(K,|\quad|)$, $m$ its maximal ideal, $\hat{A}$ is that associated to its completion, $(\hat{K}, |\quad|)$.

I believe we have to prove that this is a *homeomorphism*. He claims that because $m^n$ is both open and closed we have bijectivity.

(i) How does this follow?
(ii) How does this show the topology are the same?

Comment: Why do you believe you have to prove it is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @EricWofsey because we have a topology on both sides. Even if we were to prove set bijectivity, I do not under the argument about being closed and open. Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misread Milne. His claim is only that the map (let's call it $f$) is an isomorphism of rings, the only non-obvious part of which is bijectivity. Then, he claims that

(1) injectivity follows from $m^n$ being closed in $A$

(2) surjectivity follows from $\hat m^n$ being open in $\hat A$.

Ad (1): Notice that $m^n$ is dense in $\hat m^n$ and hence in $\ker(f) = \hat m^n \cap A$.

Ad (2): Let $\hat a \in \hat A$, and let $a_k$ be a sequence in $A$ with $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k = \hat a$. Since $\hat m^n$ is open in $\hat A$, the set $\hat a +\hat m^n$ is an open neighbourhood of $\hat a$ in $\hat A$, hence all but finitely many $a_k$ are contained in it. For all these $a_k$, we have $f(a_k+m_n) = \hat a +\hat m_n$.

After that is set and done, you can of course also conclude that $f$ is a homeomorphism, which is kind of trivial once you've noticed that (because $m^n$ is open and closed in $A$, and $\hat m^n$ is open and closed in $\hat A$) the natural (quotient) topology on both sides is the discrete topology.

Comment: If we define $\hat{A}$ as $\varprojlim A/m^n$ then it is clear $\hat{A}/\hat{m}^n = A/m^n$. Otherwise if we define $A$ as $ \{ a \in K, v(a) \ge 0\}, m = \{ a \in K, v(a) > 0\}=\{a \in K, v(a) \ge C\}$, $\hat{K}$ the completion of $K$ for $|a|=2^{-v(a)}$,$ \hat{A} = \{ a \in \hat{K}, v(a) \ge 0\}$ then it reduces to $m^n= \{a \in K, v(a) \ge mC\}, \hat{A} = \varprojlim A/m^n$

Comment: @reuns: The source (Milne) quoted by the OP defines completion via Cauchy sequences. Though I personally would prefer the projective limit approach, and agree that would make the result clear, the OP asked specifically to expand Milne's proof sketch -- which consists exactly of what I call (1) and (2).